# Error when connecting the NX1P2 with NB10W-TW01B

Tags: plc

I have tried two settings as given in the YouTube links [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3w5twZvN6s) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdUri5NODm4) but didn't work.

Here I am attaching my settings (PLC has same settings as in YouTube videos):

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings in HMI]

[image: Setting]